# variance of multiple regression coefficients

Tags: regression

If I consider universal kriging (or multiple spatial regression) in matrix form as:

${\bf{V = XA  + R }}$

where $\bf{R}$ is the residual and $\bf{A}$ are the trend coefficients, then the estimate of ${\bf{\hat A}}$ is:

${\bf{\hat A}}=(\bf{X^{T}C^{-1}X)^{-1}X^{T}C^{-1}V}$

(as I understand it), where $\bf{C}$ is the covariance matrix, if it is known. Then, the variance of the coefficients is:

$\text{VAR}({\bf{\hat A}})=(\bf{X^{T}C^{-1}X)^{-1}}$???

I am getting this from [here](http://www.math.umt.edu/graham/stat544/ukrige.pdf).

How does one get from the estimate of ${\bf{\hat A}}$, to its variance? i.e. how can I derive that variance?

Comment: Maybe I'm something of a purist on certain issues.  See this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals_in_statistics  What you're talking about here seems to be an _error_ rather than a _residual_.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. I'm coming from a geostatistics background where we model a random variable (i.e. rock porosity) often by separating the data into a trend component and a residual component (I have seen it referred to as both error and residual). The trend component is modelled deterministically and the residual is modelled either deterministically or stochastically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$$
First, recall that
$$
\var(MV) = M\Big(\var(V)\Big)M^T.
$$
so
$$
\begin{align}
& \var((X^T C^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T C^{-1}V) \\[10pt]
& = (X^T C^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T C^{-1}\Big(\var{V}\Big)\Big( (X^T C^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T C^{-1} \Big)^T. \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

Then, recall that $(AB)^T$ (with $A$ to the left of $B$) is equal to $B^T A^T$ (with $A$ to the right of $B$).  With $X^T C^{-1} X$, one cannot invert all three matrices and multiply in the opposite order, since $X$ is not a *square* matrix.  But that matrix is symmetric, i.e. it is its own transpose.  And $C$ is also symmetric, and so is $C^{-1}$.  So we get:
$$
\Big( (X^T C^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T C^{-1} \Big)^T = C^{-1}X(X^TC^{-1}X)^{-1}.
$$
Then $(1)$ becomes
$$
\begin{align}
& (X^T C^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T C^{-1}\Big(\var{V}\Big) C^{-1}X(X^TC^{-1}X)^{-1} \\[10pt]
& = (X^T C^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T C^{-1}\Big( C \Big) C^{-1}X(X^TC^{-1}X)^{-1} \\[10pt]
& = (X^T C^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T C^{-1} X(X^TC^{-1}X)^{-1} \\[10pt]
& = (X^T C^{-1}X)^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @FluxCapacitor : If you like this answer, could you "accept" it and up-vote it?

Comment: Sadly, I do not have the reputation to up-vote it. I would up-vote it twice if I could.